# “Uncaught(in promise):TypeError:Cannot read property ‘submitted’ of undefined”

Tags: angularjs, navigation

I want to warn user when user is trying to navigate away from the page(components) making some changes .so I implemented using this article https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/angular-how-keep-user-from-lost-his-data-by-accidentally-leaving-the-page-before-submit-4eeb74420f0d,but I am getting this error

> “Uncaught(in promise):TypeError:Cannot read property ‘submitted’ of
>   undefined” and “Uncaught(in promise):TypeError:Cannot read property
>   ‘dirty’ of undefined” when I was trying to navigate from the component
>   without making changes.

Could someone please help me with this.Trying to solve this error from 2 days.
Thanks
ps:these errors are coming from can-deactivate method.

Comment: first of all, the link gives me 404 error, secondable show us your code

Comment: I will give that link again:

Comment: https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/angular-how-keep-user-from-lost-his-data-by-accidentally-leaving-the-page-before-submit-4eeb74420f0d

Answer (score 0):

case 1:This basically happens when the code is not able to reach your form. In some apps there are some forms which will display when you click some buttons or perform any actions,Otherwise the form will not be there in that page.So whenever you are checking (this.form.submitted or this.form.dirty) make sure form is present.So just add one if statement like this:

```
if(this.form){
    if(this.form.submitted || !this.form.dirty){
      return true;
    }
}
```

case 2:This will also happens when you don't implement abstract methods/accessors in your component.